# AutoMapper C# - Set default value for all unmapped string in destination

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm new to AutoMapper, and trying convert object to bigger (means more fields) object. 
I'm looking for a way to set default value for all destination's string fields.
Currently couldn't find a way to define general condition for all string fields.

Assume:

```
  class A
{
    public string a { get; set; }

}

class B
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string c { get; set; }
}
```

Then when using mapper:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, B>());       
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            B map = mapper.Map<B>(new A {a = "f"});
```

The unmapped strings' value is null.
I'm looking for a way to set the unmapped strings to `string.Empty`.
Using the `config.ForAllMembers(...)`.
Note: I know I can use specific `ForMember` for each field like:

```
 var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<A, B>()
           .ForMember(des => des.b, x=> x.MapFrom(src => string.Empty)));
```

But it isn't so good. Why?

1. Some times I have fields that their value isn't guaranteed, it may be null or 
   a valid value so I need to pay attention for such case.
2. In real case I have many fields, so it's not a comfortable solution to define such rule for every field.

There is an easy solution for such need?

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to resolve in the following manner:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.field, act => act.MapFrom(src => String.IsNullOrEmpty(src.field) ? "N/A" : src.field))
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use ForAllOtherMembers.

```
    c.CreateMap<A, B>().ForAllOtherMembers(o=>
    {
        if(((PropertyInfo)o.DestinationMember).PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            o.MapFrom(s=>"default");
        }
    });
```

Comment: It looks near to the desired, but it also overrides the value of `B.b`. It is now `default` instead of `f` as assigned. It seems small fix needed. Thanks!

Comment: That's true. But a more complete solution is too complicated as far as I'm concerned. But possible :)

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?q=GetUnmappedPropertyNames&unscoped_q=GetUnmappedPropertyNames

Answer (score 0):

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.field, act => act.MapFrom(src => default))
```

put default as defaultValue directly.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach which gives more control for your default values to be set in the destination class

```cs
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "Guest";
}
public class UserDtoProfile : Profile
{
    public UserDtoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForAllMembers((c) =>
            {
                c.UseDestinationValue();
            });
    }
}
```